# Компиляция Java-сервлетов на Linux

Tags: servlet, java, tomcat, linux

Использую библиотеку `javax.servlet`. Основываясь на [официальной документации](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), компилятор подцепляет (или по крайней мере должен) библиотеки как из `CATALINA-BASE/lib`, так и из `CATALINA-BASE/common`. Проверил конфиг - так и есть, в `catalina.properties` в сроке `common.loader` прописаны пути к `.jar-файлам`:

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,\
${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,\
/var/lib/tomcat7/common/classes,/var/lib/tomcat7/common/*.jar
```

Однако компиляция успешно валится, так как библиотек якобы нету:

> UploadServlet.java:6: package javax.servlet does not exist

Работаю на `Ubuntu`, сервлет-машина - `Tomcat7`, установил из стандартных репозиториев убунты. Компилирую из командной строки.

В чём может быть причина?

P. S. Всё проходит гладко, если в параметр `javac -cp` прописывать путь к конкретному `.jar-архиву` с библиотекой. Но подключать таким образом все необходимые библиотеки - чёрт ногу сломит.

Comment: В -cp можно указывать путь к библиотекам, а не отдельный jar-файл. 

Или поправить переменную окружения CLASSPATH.

Comment: Можно, однако и такой вариант не работает.
В каком именно месте Вы предлагаете изменить CLASSPATH? Я добавлял и в ~/.bashrc, и в /etc/environment, однако результат пока один и тот же

Comment: @xphoenyx, странно... у меня в "/etc/environment" лечилось.

Answer (score 1):

для текущего экземпляра оболочки можно воспользоваться встроенной командой `export` (разделяя пути символом <kbd>:</kbd>):

```
$ export CLASSPATH=путь1:путь2:путь3
$ команда компиляции 1
$ команда компиляции 2
...
```